# DB Connection failed {"The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle.1' provider is not registered on the local machine."}

Tags: loadrunner, dbconnection

1) I am not sure what provider i need to use
2) When I try to register "regsvr32.exe OraOLEDB11.dll" I am getting error that the "oraoledb11.dll is loaded but entry point server is not found"

Below is the code I am using: 
lr_db_connect("StepName=Connect",
        "ConnectionString=Data Source=( DESCRIPTION =( ADDRESS_LIST = ( ADDRESS = ( PROTOCOL = TCP )( HOST = <> )( PORT = 1521 )))( CONNECT_DATA = ( SERVER = DEDICATED )( SERVICE_NAME = <> ) ) ); User Id=<>; Password =<>;Connection Timeout=30;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle",
        "ConnectionName=OracleDB",
        "ConnectionType=OLEDB",
LAST );

Answer (score 0):

Context?

- Hand coded or recorded
- VUGEN or Load Generator
- Oracle client installed and working successfully